# Float left div at the bottom of right

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is my current html:

```css
.left { width:50%; float:left; }
.right { width:50%; float:left; }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">This is left content</div>
        <div class="right">This is left content</div>
    </div>
```

with this css, for smaller resolution `right` div goes under `left` div, but i want opposite, i want `left` div to go under `right`.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, Im using media queries for responsive layout. I've already applied media queries for different screen resolutions. What i wanted to do is to maintain the sequence for desktop i.e. LEFT div then RIGHT div. But for mobile devices LEFT DIV should show under RIGHT div.
@GCyrillus sample code is exactly what i wanted. Here's the solution if anyone else having the same issue.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYGKjp

Comment: As a side-note: percentage values should not be quoted.

Comment: Also, define *smaller resolution* please. Smaller that what?

Comment: @shridhar can you explain how z-index would help here?

Comment: resolution is already without quotes, it was a typo, @Hashem for smaller resolution i meant to say mobile devices. Im working on responsive layout.

Comment: you could have drop the float for flex , flex-direction and order without touching html structure

Comment: @Kevin your div goes under other div because of invalid css width property. It should not be quoted. After you fix that - div's would not jump one above another. Is that what you needed or div's MUST go one above another at low width screens?

Comment: @Kevin Does this help? http://jsbin.com/hugisajozi/1/edit

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYGKjp flex and media queri set at 600px for demo, is it more like what you look for ?

Comment: @Kevin your question was not clear and the mediaquerie  part was missing. that was a guess

Comment: @GCyrillus your solution works on desktop but not on mobile. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

You can do two things here, either float them right instead of left, or change your markup as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">This is left content</div>
    <div class="left">This is left content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had typed almost the identical answer, word for word lol Great minds and all that :)

Comment: Geniuses, thats what we are :p

Comment: If his question was about how to make to go one div above another at low width screens - you are not :)

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the order with right and left divs.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">This is right content</div>
    <div class="left">This is left content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left { width:50%; float:left; }
.right { width:50%; float:left; }
```

Comment: cannot switch the order, the order should be LEFT and then RIGHT for desktop and for mobile device the left div should go under right one. @GCyrillus answer is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the divs around

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">This is right content</div>
  <div class="left">This is left content</div>
</div>
```